# Strange characters written to SQLite file - Trying to store byte array in SQLlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm try to convert a file into a byte array, and then convert the byte array into a string for storage in a SQLite database. These files are very small, typically just 10kb audio files.

My problem is that the data written to the SQLite database looks like the below four characters, rather than a 10kb string.

```
���d
```

The file is stored in an IFormFile and then converted to a byte array.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadSound(IFormFile SoundFile)
    {
        // convert to base 64
        byte[] fileData = null;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await SoundFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            fileData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The byte array is then converted to a string with UTF8 encoding

```
     Sound sound = new Sound();        
     sound.SoundString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData);
```

This string is then saved to the SQLite database using the entity framework

```
    db.Sounds.Add(sound);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

If I step through the program and check the value of `sound.SoundString` before saving, it will contain the full 10kb byte array. However only the four `���d` characters are written to the database.

I'm wondering if SQLite is having issues with the UTF8 encoding. However I haven't been able to find a fix.

Comment: Storing binary data as text/string is...problematic. Base64 text will work but why not just store it as binary?

Comment: @NewContributor I was under the (possibly incorrect) belief that storing as binary didn't yet work in EF core.

Comment: Converting arbitrary bytes to a string won't work either.

Comment: @TidyDev What? I've been storing `byte[]`s to a SQL Server database (and then reading them) since EF Core 1.0 preview 2

Comment: You cannot store arbitrary bytes as UTF-8 because UTF-8 [has rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences). The reason SQLite “has issues” is because your `fileData` doesn't follow the rules.

Comment: Why not using SQLite `BLOB` column type? I believe it works (at least in the latest at this time EF Core 2.1.4).

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, i'll give that a try.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually if you define the property as `byte[]`, EF Core migration will set it up correctly for you.

Comment: @IvanStoev you were correct, defining the property as `byte[]` and setting the SQLite column type to `BLOB` worked fine.